# Immutable.js Record.set type checking with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, immutable.js

I'm using Immutable.js with TypeScript to build a Redux app.

Essentially, my State looks like

```
const defaultState = {
  booleanValue: true,
  numberValue: 0,
}

const StateRecord = Immutable.Record(defaultState)

class StateClass extends StateRecord {
  booleanValue: boolean
  numberValue: number
}

const STATE = new StateClass()
```

(This setup enables compile-time type checking for expressions like `STATE.booleanValue === 'hi'`)

Is there any way to enable compile-time type checking for `set`, such as `STATE.set('booleanValue', 'hi')`? (I want an warning from compiler saying `'booleanValue' cannot be set to 'hi'`.)

Or, is there alternative setup to make Immutable.js and TypeScript work together both when getting and setting?

Answer (score 1):

> is there alternative setup to make Immutable.js and TypeScript work together both when getting and setting

Not without wrapping up the `StateRecord` in helper functions (basically throwing more code at it that needs to be duplicated and kept in sync). So in short nope.